# Reached end of file while parsing in java language

Tags: java, parsing, syntax-error

// TODO: Define a class: StringInstrument that is derived from the Instrument class

```
public class StringInstrument extends Instrument {
   public class StringInstrument extends Instrument {

    private int numStrings;
    private int numFrets;

    public void setNumOfStrings(int numStrings) {
        this.numStrings = numStrings;
    }

    public void setNumOfFrets(int numFrets) {
        this.numFrets = numFrets;
    }

    public int getNumOfStrings() {
        return numStrings;
    }

    public int getNumOfFrets() {
        return numFrets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Theres a duplicate `public class StringInstrument extends Instrument {` at the beginning of the file. Remove it

Comment: Please remove duplicate statement block. public class StringInstrument extends Instrument {
   public class StringInstrument extends Instrument {

Answer (score 0):

The error Reached End of File While Parsing is a compiler error and almost always means that your curly parenthesis are not ending completely or maybe there could be extra parenthesis in the end.

Every opening braces { needs one closing braces }. The only purpose of the extra braces is to provide scope-limit.

So, Check if you have left behind any braces without closing it. Or if you added an extra brace without any use.

P.S : The code you shared isnt much clear. (Got confused by the extra brace you added in the question outside of the code)